# std::ifstream::gcount() returns 1 byte too much

Tags: c++, sockets, fstream

While sending and receiving a file with sockets I encountered that I am reading 1 byte too much (int value 81 'Q').

I can cut it off while reading the file (client side) or while receiving from the socket (server side) but where does this extra byte come from?

**Client:**

```
// set up byte streaming
char buffer[BUF];
std::ifstream is;

is.open(path, std::ofstream::in | std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::app);

if (is) {
    while (1) {
        is.read(buffer, BUF);
        if (is) {
            send(socket, &buffer, BUF, 0);
        } else {
            // cut it off with   "is.gcount()-1"
            send(socket, &buffer, is.gcount(), 0);
            break;
        }
    }
    is.close();
}
```

**Server:**

```
// set up streaming, the client already sent the number of bytes we expect
std::string path(temp);
path += "/";
path += f.name;
int ok = 1;
char buffer[BUF];
long expected = f.size, received = 0, chunk = 0;
std::ofstream os;

os.open(path, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);

/** read until we received @file.size bytes */
while (received < expected) {
    printf("%ld / %ld\n", expected, received);
    // read from socket
    // receive bytes and get number of received bytes
    chunk = recv(sd, &buffer, BUF, 0); 
    if (chunk < 0) {
        /** TODO error and delete */
        ok = 0;
        break;
    }
    // write to file, chunk-- cuts it off if chunk size != buffer size
    os.write(buffer, chunk);
    // update number of already received bytes
    received += chunk;
}

if (ok) {
    /** TODO copy file to @www folder */
}

printf("%ld / %ld\n", expected, received);
```

Server side output:

```
server.cpp      2517
2517 / 0
2517 / 1024
2517 / 2048
2517 / 2518 < 1 byte too much
```

Comment: You have a few missing details here. Present your [MCVE].

Comment: If the last `is.read(buffer, BUF)` ends up reading fewer, remaining bytes, from the end of the file, the subsequent code will still send BUF bytes to the socket.

Comment: Okay, while writing the minimal code I saw my mistake ... I am always reading BUF bytes also if the bytes do not belong to the file ... dumb mistake -.-